# Normal Operators: Polar Decomposition (Rudin)

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

On page 332 theorem 12.35b) of Rudin functional analysis is show that if T is normal then it has a polar decomposition $T=UP$. Does he mean that $P=|T|$? He's a bit ambiguous as to how he defines polar decomposition in whether $P$ is simply positive or whether $P=|T|$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\lvert T\rvert$? $P = \sqrt{T^\ast T}$, however.

Comment: It means $P$ is positive semidefinite. Polar decomposition is a product $UP$ such that $U$ is unitary and $P$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: @DanielFischer $|T|={\sqrt{T^*T}}$. His proof suggests he simply means $P$ is positive rather than $P=|T|$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that Rudin requires the $U$ in the polar decomposition to be a unitary. In that case, if $T=UP$, then 
$$
T^*T=PU^*UP=P^2,
$$
and indeed $P=|T|$. So there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Why does Rudin use theorem 12.32 to justify $P$ is positive? If $P=|T|$, then of course $P$ is positive. @Martin Argerami

Comment: In 12.35 b), he is **proving** that $UP$ is a polar decomposition.

Comment: Yes he has to prove $T=U|T|$ and $U$ is unitary. I just don't get the point of proving $P=|T|$ is positive when you already know it. @Martin Argerami

Comment: Or is it simply that he only knows $P=|T|$ at the end of the proof.

Comment: Another thing which is odd is that he implies the polar decomposition is not unique. Yet if $U,U'$ are unitary then clearly $U|T|=U'|T|$ implies $U=U'$

Comment: The way I see the proof, he uses functional calculus to get $U$ and $P$. Since I haven't been reading the book, it is not obvious to me if at that stage of the book it is obvious that if $f(t)=|t|$, then $f(T)=(T^*T)^{1/2}$.

Comment: As for your last comment, that is not true. Let $$T=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, \ U=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\ U'=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then $U|T|=U'|T|$, with $U\ne U'$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a complex Hilbert space. For any $T\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ (normal or not), there is a unique $P\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ such that $P \ge 0$ and $P^{2}=T^{\star}T$. So your question is confusing. If you define $|T|$ to be a positive square root of $T^{\star}T$, then any $P \ge 0$ for which $P^{2}=T^{\star}T$ must be $|T|$.

Comment: The point is that restricting to normals guarantees a unitary. *(See example above.)*

Answer (score 1):

*Rudin restricts to normals as...*

**Definition**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider selfadjoint operators:
$$H:\mathcal{D}H\subseteq\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}:\quad H=H^*$$

> Define positivity by:*
>   $$H\geq0:\iff\sigma(H)\geq0$$

**(They may be unbounded!)*

**Positive Operators**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider positive operators:
$$P^{(\prime)}:\mathcal{D}P^{(\prime)}\subseteq\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}:\quad P^{(\prime)}\geq0$$

By functional calculus:
$$P^2=P'^2\implies P=P'$$

That gives uniqueness.

**Closed Operators**

Given *two* Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$.

Consider a closed operator:
$$A:\mathcal{D}A\subseteq\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{K}:\quad A=A^{**}$$

By closedness one obtains:
$$|A|:\mathcal{D}|A|\subseteq\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}:\quad |A|:=\sqrt{A^*A}\geq0$$

By functional calculus:*
$$\mathcal{D}:=\mathcal{D}A=\mathcal{D}|A|$$

By square root lemma:*
$$\|A\varphi\|=\||A|\varphi\|\quad(\varphi\in\mathcal{D})$$

Thus one can find:
$$J\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K}):\quad A=J|A|$$

By above and boundedness:
$$\varphi\in\overline{\mathcal{R}|A|}:\quad\|J\varphi\|_\mathcal{K}=\|\varphi\|_\mathcal{H}$$

Concluding closed operators.

**Normal Operators**

Given *one* Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a normal operator:
$$N:\mathcal{D}N\subseteq\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}:\quad N^*N=NN^*$$

Then it is closed:
$$N^*N=NN^*\implies N=N^{**}$$

So the above applies:
$$J\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad N=J|N|$$

And it is isometric on:
$$\varphi\in\overline{\mathcal{R}|N|}:\quad\|J\varphi\|_\mathcal{H}=\|\varphi\|_\mathcal{H}$$

By above and normality:**
$$\left(\overline{\mathcal{R}|N|}\right)^\perp=\mathcal{N}|N|=\mathcal{N}N=\mathcal{N}(N^*N)\\
=\mathcal{N}(NN^*)=\mathcal{N}N^*=\left(\overline{\mathcal{R}N}\right)^\perp$$

So it can be chosen unitary.

**Partial Isometry**

Given *one* Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Consider the right shift:
$$A:\ell^2(\mathbb{N})\to\ell^2(\mathbb{N}):\quad A:=R$$

Its modulus is the unit:
$$A^*A=LR=1\implies|A|=1$$

Thus partial isometry is:
$$A=J|A|\implies J=R$$

But it is not unitary:
$$\mathcal{R}J=\mathcal{R}R\neq\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$$

Concluding partial isometry.

*(Note it was even isometric!)*

**See the thread: [Square Root](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/997186/79762)*

***See the thread: [Kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1361113/79762)*