# Polar Decomposition: Unitarity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Prove that the left and right shifts on $l_{2}$ have no polar decomposition (i.e. $UP$ where $U$ is unitary and $P$ is positive).

Answer (score 1):

**Left Shift**

Denote for shorthand:
$$1_0(0,x_1,\ldots):=(0,x_1,\ldots)$$

For the modulus:
$$L^*L=RL=1_0\implies|L|=1_0$$

For the argument:
$$L=U|L|\implies U=1_0,1,\ldots$$

So it admits *one*.

**Right Shift**

For the modulus:
$$R^*R=LR=1\implies|R|=1$$

For the argument:
$$R=U|R|\implies U=R$$

So it admits *none*.

**Reference**

For *much* more details: [Polar Decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1361022/79762)

Comment: In your first line do you mean $1_0(\color{red}{x_1},x_2,\ldots):=(0,\color{red}{x_2},\ldots)$?

Comment: I thought we had $$R L (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) = R(x_2, x_3, \ldots) = (0, x_2, x_3, \ldots),$$ implying that $$|L| (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) = RL (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)  = (0, x_2, x_3, \ldots)$$ Then we have $$L (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) = (x_2, x_3, \ldots) \overset{!}{=} (U | L |) x = U (0, x_2, x_3, \ldots),$$ implying $U(x_1, x_2, \ldots) = (x_2, x_3,\ldots)$ What you mean by "$U = 1_0, 1, \ldots$"?

Comment: The sequences in this post were meant to start with $x_0$, i.e. $(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$.